# how to control size of an image in backend asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have form and and admin should choose a picture.
and picture must be 400*300. 
how can I send a validation message when admin uploaded unrecommended photo?

```
public ActionResult Gallery(Gallery gallery, HttpPostedFileBase imageUrl)
{
    if (imageUrl.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(imageUrl.ToString());
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Images"), 
                                                fileName);
        imageUrl.SaveAs(path);
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you want a validation test for the picture to have a maximum size of 400*300?

Comment: No. exactly 400*300

Comment: Ok, what have you already tried? Can I see some code?

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before saving the file with

```
imageUrl.SaveAs(path);
```

as you do, you can first create an image, like this:

```
Image myImage = Image.FromStream(imageUrl.InputStream);
```

There on that Image class are infos about the image and you can save from an image too:

```
if (myImage.Height != 400 || myImage.Width != 300) {
  // ... your code the inform the user
} else {
  myImage.Save(path);
}
```

However, instead of forcing the user to upload a photo with the exactly right width and high (the user might have not such a photo), you could also downsize the photo in your C# code. I usually use ThumbnailSharp available on nuget. I think that gives the user a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileInfo` property to get the filesize (in bytes), the `Bitmap` contains the filesize (width and height).
You can now test on `imgHeight` and `imgWidth`

I think you only need the bitmap properties but just in case, I also put the code for the filesize in bytes.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(open.FileName);
var sizeInBytes = file.Length;

Bitmap img = new Bitmap(open.FileName);

var imgHeight = img.Height;
var imgWidth = img.Width;
```